# C++ with Sqlite3 crash on creating DB on Release version

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have created a GUI app with the sqlite3 database.

When debugging with Visual Studio 2022 it runs fine and sqlite3 is working.

When I make the release version and install it on my laptop it crashes when I start doing something that involves sqlite3.

I'm getting a message when building: warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100002E) for 'sqlite3'; image may not run

Can someone explain why this happens?

I have added all dll files and lib files. Everything works fine, except sqlite3, sometimes it will not crash, but nothing happens that is related to database.

This is method that creates sqlite3 table and crashes app, it closes without any messages or errors.

```
public: void createDbTable() {

   sqlite3* db;

   std::string sql = "CREATE TABLE TRUCK_WEIGHT("
             "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
             "TRUCK_NUMBER           CHAR(50)  NOT NULL, "
             "ARRIVAL_TIME          TEXT     NOT NULL, "
             "ARRIVAL_WEIGHT            INTEGER     NOT NULL, "
             "DEPART_TIME          TEXT     NOT NULL, "
             "DEPART_WEIGHT            INTEGER     NOT NULL, "
             "AXLE1_WEIGHT             INTEGER     NOT NULL, "
             "AXLE2_WEIGHT             INTEGER     NOT NULL, "
             "AXLE3_WEIGHT             INTEGER     NOT NULL, "
             "AXLE4_WEIGHT             INTEGER     NOT NULL, "
             "AXLE5_WEIGHT             INTEGER     NOT NULL, "
             "AXLE6_WEIGHT             INTEGER     NOT NULL, "
             "AXLE7_WEIGHT             INTEGER     NOT NULL, "
             "AXLE8_WEIGHT            INTEGER     NOT NULL);";


   int exit = 0;
   exit = sqlite3_open("truck_weight.db", &db);
   char* messageError;
   exit = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), NULL, 0, &messageError);

   if (exit != SQLITE_OK) {
       sqlite3_free(messageError);
   }
   else {
        sqlite3_close(db);
   }
}
```

Comment: You have already asked that [C++ with Sqlite3 crash on creating DB on Release version \[closed\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77579159/c-with-sqlite3-crash-on-creating-db-on-release-version) and got a good answer in the comment.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you compile the sqlite3 amalgamated .c file into your program?

Comment: You should make sure `sqlite3_open()` succeeds before trying to do anything with the connection.

Comment: Botje - No, I have tried it and nothing changed. 
Shawn - Sure, but that will not solve the problem, why sqlite3 isn`t working on release version. 
273K - There was problem with that post, so I considered to delete it. Still working on that, but hopefully someone have faced the same issue and knows why it happens. I have tried everything I could imagine.

Comment: The app will crash in both situations when it is on the PC where it was developed and on others too.

Comment: And now I`m getting some error description: 
The pointer passed in as a String must not be in the bottom 64K of the process's address space.

Comment: if (sqlite3_open("truck_weight.db", &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
 this->label2->Text = "db not opened";
 return;
}
It wont open database. How I can know why?

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks to everyone.